# How in php8 make match with more complicated conditions?

Tags: php-8

As php8 allows match like :

```
echo match ($v) {
    0 => 'Foo',
    1 => 'Bar',
    2 => 'Baz',
};  // Bar
```

I wonder if there is a way to use in match more complicated conditions, like :

```
  if ($checkValueType == EnumType::Integer and ! isValidInteger($value) and ! empty
        ($default_value)) {
        return $default_value;
    }
    if ($checkValueType == EnumType::Float and ! isValidFloat($value) and ! empty($default_value)) {
        return $default_value;
    }
    if ($checkValueType == EnumType::Bool and ! isValidBool($value) and ! empty($default_value)) {
        return $default_value;
    }

    return $value;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that, because [match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php#control-structures.match) is an expression, and cannot contain statements.

**Structure of a match expression**

```
$return_value = match (subject_expression) {
    single_conditional_expression => return_expression,
    conditional_expression1, conditional_expression2 => return_expression,
};
```